# Detect multi-touch finger positions in IE10/IE11

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, multi-touch

I'm developing in JavaScript for IE10/IE11, and am trying to get custom multi-touch events to work. I'm using the MSGesture API, and it provides a nice abstraction layer, but I would like access to the underlying positions of the touched points. Is there a way to get this?

I guess it could be calculated from the initial offset, using the scale/translation information, but was thinking there would probably be a cleaner way?

Example code:

```
container.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", function (e) {
    // We have access to e.g. 
    // e.scale / e.translationX / e.translationY

    // Now, this is what we need, but it's only for one finger
    // (or is it an average somehow?)
    // e.offsetX 
    // e.offsetY

    // Is it possible to get offsetX/Y for each finger (pointer)?

}, false);
```

Comment: As it turns out, there is no way to calculate from initial offset either, as the event only provides the position of the center point of the touches. It seems the only way is to manually keep track of touched points with MSPointerDown/Up events.